# "Transpose" of a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I'm having quite a bit of trouble figuring out exactly how to rearrange a table. I have a large table that looks something like this:

```
+--------+-----------+
|  NAME  | ACCOUNT # |
+--------+-----------+
| Nike   |        87 |
| Nike   |        12 |
| Adidas |        80 |
| Adidas |        21 |
+--------+-----------+
```

And I want to rearrange it to look like this:

```
+------+--------+
| Nike | Adidas |
+------+--------+
|   87 |     80 |
|   12 |     21 |
+------+--------+
```

But I can't seem to figure out how. I tried using PIVOT, but that only works with aggregate functions. I tried using a FOR LOOP as well, but couldn't get it work just right.

Comment: Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: show us some SQL. If you don't need to aggregate use MIN or MAX functions

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways, but all being by enumerating the rows.  Here is an example using conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when name = 'Nike' then account end) as Nike,
       max(case when name = 'Adidas' then account end) as Adidas
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by account desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this doesn't work for me - I should have mentioned, but there are something like 200 names so I can't really write out a conditional statement for each one.

Comment: @TinaBelcher . . . You *can*.  You might find a spreadsheet helpful for generating the code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider again a pivot solution but first adding a rownumber for rolling `Name` group counts. Below assumes an autonumber `ID` field:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT Name, "Account #", 
         (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID)) GrpRowNum
         /* ALT: (SELECT Count(*) FROM Table1 sub 
          *       WHERE sub.Name = Table1.Name AND sub.ID <= Table1.ID) GrpRowNum */             
  FROM Table1
)
PIVOT
(
  SUM("Account #")
  FOR Name IN ('Nike', 'Adidas')
)
ORDER BY RowNum;
```

However, for your ~200 items, you cannot easily render the Pivot's `IN` clause without various workarounds including `PIVOT XML` output or stored procedures with PL/SQL. Similarly, you could use general purpose coding (Java, PHP, Python, R) to retreive `SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Table1` resultset in vector/array, joining element values (collapsing or imploding arrays) with quotes and comma separators, and dropping the entire list in `IN` clause.